# How to make a controlled "shuffle" order?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, algorithm, shuffle

I have a set of quiz game questions in a sql database (javascript and sqlite actually).  The questions all have a difficulty level from 1 to 5, 5 being hardest. Here is a simplified visualization of the data...

```
+---------+--------------+  
|   id    | difficulty   |   
+---------+--------------+  
| 1       |      1       |    
| 2       |      5       |    
| 3       |      2       |    
| 4       |      3       |    
| 5       |      2       | 
| 6       |      2       |    
| 7       |      4       |    
| 8       |      1       |    
| 9       |      5       |    
| 10      |      3       |      
+---------+--------------+
```

Now I can shuffle these fine in sql or code so they are in a random order with no repeats but I also want to have control over the way the difficulty field is ordered.

So for instance I could have a shuffled set of question where the difficulty level order looks like this...

1,1,5,2,3,3,2,2,2,4

This has several 'clumps' of difficulty, that's not what I want.  The user playing the game would get several groups of the similarly difficult questions. An order like this would be better...

1,2,3,2,5,4,1,2,3,2

I want to ensure the questions are shuffled but without difficulty clumping.  An even spread of difficulty where there are few, if any 'clumps'.  Any help on the MySQL/javascript (or PHP) would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'clumps'. Do you mean you want random questions without contiguous repeated difficulty? Can it start with any difficulty value or it should always start with 1?

Comment: It can start with any difficulty and yes I mean without contiguous difficulty.  Clumps would be contiguous difficulty.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "runs", not "clumps".

Is the size of the input fixed? E.g. do you have to take N questions and reorder them so there are no runs? Or do you want to extract N questions out of a set of M, where N<M?

Comment: The size of the input is fixed. I'll be reordering all of the set.  Also the difficulty is weighted to the middle (2s,3s and 4s) which is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of grouping all the ids together why don't you group them by difficulty randomize each section and then pull them out one by one.  Or once they are randomly sorted you could pull them from a random difficulty, then remove that difficulty level until you have a question from each.

This is what I was thinking about in answer to sje397, so I'll add it to my answer.

As long as all the other choices add up to the largest group minus one you will have no clumping (assuming your algorithm is correct). However, the algorithm would basically take the form of pick from A (group with greatest number of choices), pick from another group, pick from A etc. until A is equal to the size of the other groups. So the best algorithm would check to find the largest group and pick from it.  It would then pick from another group, then check to see what group is the largest, then choose from it unless it is the previously chosen one etc.

Comment: +1 because this solution handles data-sets that cannot avoid grouping better than njk's solution. You could alter the solution so that it takes in account the proportions of elements in each group when determining which group to select from next. This would give you an optimal result.

Comment: True the easiest to handle is if there is an even number of questions in each difficulty, but from the example I don't think that is the case.  So some extra work would have to be done.

Comment: Some clumping must happen if one group is larger than the rest, but not necessarily if there are two groups of equal size larger than the rest. Either way, you would just need to pick from the largest group more often - pick as you've suggested but with a probability based on the size of items remaining in the group.

Comment: @sje397 Yes that is what I meant by 'extra work'  I didn't really make myself clear.  Check the answer I updated it.

Comment: This is pretty much the approach I have taken.  The 'extra work' on merging all the different difficulties is the hard part here.  I have something that works ok but I'm looking into applying a merge sort algorithm to this and altering it for uneven elements.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following strategy, in code: (the following was a bulleted list, but I couldn't get code appearing after a bulleted list to display correctly - I thoroughly detest this "markdown" garbage this site uses)

order the questions by difficulty

split the questions halfway into two lists, an "easy" list and a "hard" list

take questions one by one from the easy and hard lists, alternating between the two. (This would mean that you would have a slight trend from easy to difficult over the sequence of questions, which you might or might not be OK with.)

Primitive implementation:

```
$resultset = your_preferred_query_function('SELECT id FROM question ORDER BY difficulty');
$questions_temp = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc() ) {
    $questions_temp[] = $row['id'];
}
if ( count($questions) % 2 ) {
    $loop_limit = (count($questions) - 1) / 2;
    $halfway = (count($questions) + 1) / 2;
    $questions[0] = $questions_temp[$loop_limit];
} else {
    $loop_limit = count($questions) / 2;
    $halfway = count($questions) / 2;
    $questions = array();
}
for ($i=0; $i<$loop_limit; $i++) {
    $questions[] = $questions_temp[$i];
    $questions[] = $questions_temp[$halfway+$i];
}
```

Now `$questions` is an array containing questions ordered as I suggested.

Comment: FYI: agree about the markdown thing, key is: there has to be at least 1 visible character between a bullet list and code-block. I've resorted to a single dot on the line before.

Answer (score 1):

Well in a truly random sample 'clumps' *do* naturally appear. So if you want to remove these you have to enforce something manually, e.g. specify a pattern of difficulty and choosing a random question matching each difficulty level

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through a randomly-shuffled input array and whenever you hit an element with the same difficulty level as the one before it, swap with the next element that doesn't have the same difficulty level. Just in my head, I think that this would turn your initial input into: 1,5,1,2,3,2,3,2,4,2

Depending on the input, this approach might cause clumping at the end but might be good enough...

If your input is bigger than what you need, you could also just remove any element that has the same difficulty as the one before it.

Comment: For even less clumping, treat the array as circular, and when looking for a swap candidate, stop when you're back at the current position.

Comment: Won't this just push the clumps to the end?

Comment: @Dolphin: treating the array as circular won't push the clumps to the end, no.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution (it's not very efficient though) would be to do:

```
<?php

        define('MAX_QUESTIONS',10);

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=so;host=127.0.0.1","","");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM q group by difficulty order by rand()";
        $data = $dbh->query($sql);
        $rows = $data->fetchAll();
        $ids = getIds($rows);
        while (count($rows) < MAX_QUESTIONS ) {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM q where id not in ".
                       "(".join(",",$ids).") group by difficulty order by rand()";
                $data = $dbh->query($sql);
                $more_rows = $data->fetchAll();
                $rows = array_merge($rows,$more_rows);
                $ids = getIds($rows);
        }
        print_r($rows);

        function getIds($data) {
                $ids = array();
                foreach ($data as $v) {
                        $ids[] = $v['id'];
                }
                return $ids;
        }

?>
```

This is needed because MySQL's group by always return the same ids, regardless of if you've ordered previously (even in a subquery.)

The good thing about this is that it guarantees no 'clumps' (at the potential cost of returning empty for the final question that would create a 'clump', you could special case that, though)

The bad thing is that you need more than a single query, and that ordering by rand() is awfully inefficient, but if your table is small it probably won't actually matter.